# Why does Jest throw an error on dynamic import() when calculating coverage for a Vue.js app?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have a Vue.js application that is covered by unit tests written in Jest.

When I run Jest, my unit tests work and pass green but then Jest breaks when collecting coverage data - with the below error:

```
Failed to collect coverage from C:\...\router.js
ERROR: C:/.../router.js: Unexpected token (7:19)
STACK: SyntaxError: C:/.../router.js: Unexpected token (7:19)
   5 | Vue.use(Router);
   6 | 
>  7 | const feed = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "foo" */'~/components/pages/feed/FeedPage').then(cmp => cmp.default || cmp);
     |                    ^
   8 | const lobby = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "foo" */'~/components/pages/lobby/LobbyPage').then(cmp => cmp.default || cmp);
   9 | const home = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "foo" */'~/components/pages/home/Home').then(cmp => cmp.default || cmp);
  10 | const wip = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "global" */'~/components/pages/wip/WorkInProgressPage').then(cmp => cmp.default || cmp);
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3627:50)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3344:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseFunctionBody (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4226:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseArrowExpression (C:\...\tests\unit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4190:8)

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 3.22% ( 840/26062 )
Branches     : 0.67% ( 123/18349 )
Functions    : 1.2% ( 96/7986 )
Lines        : 5.19% ( 828/15961 )
================================================================================
```

Here is my Jest configuration as part of package.json.

```
"jest": {
    "rootDir": "../",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "<rootDir>/tests/unit/node_modules/jest-vue-preprocessor",
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/tests/unit/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^~/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
    },
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,vue}",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
        "html",
        "text-summary"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "notify": true,
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/tests/setup.js"
}
```

As you can see, Jest complains about the use of the `import()` function in my router.js file. **Why do I get the above error and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stemmed from a Babel configuration that did not support dynamic imports.

Resolved by:

1. Installing [@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import)

   `npm i @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`
2. Adding it to .babelrc like so: 

   `{
       ...
       "plugins": [
           "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
       ],
       ...
   }`